# НЕ могу скомпилировать

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea

Ошибка при компиляции `Error:(4, 26) java: package javafx.application does not exist`
JDK установливал отсюда `http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk10-downloads-4416644.html`
Idea - IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.5

Ответ :
Проблема в файле `pom.xml` , поменял версию `maven-compiler-plugin` с `1.8` на `1.9` и все заработало.

```
<configuration>
                    <source>1.9</source>
                    <target>1.9</target>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Проверьте [language level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47376636/javafx-does-not-exist-using-java-9-and-intellij-idea) в свойствах проекта и конфигурации maven/gradle

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)

Comment: напишите ответ, если не трудно

Answer (score 4):

`javafx` не включается в пакет JDK. Его нужно устанавливать отдельно. Поищите в гугле, откуда скачать и как установить (конкретно для вашей системы и вашей среды разработки) этот пакет.

Comment: Спасибо, установил но проблема осталась. Новый проект на javaFx могу создать и запустить, а со старым проблемы.

Comment: Некоторые уточнения должны вам помочь. Уточните какая система? Какая версия jdk, какая версия javafx. Установлены ли системные переменные? Знает ли сама IDE о всех этих параметрах?